# Why is the times method needed when using the map method?

Tags: ruby, methods

I have a question regarding the usage of the "map" method. How come I'm getting a "No Method Error" at line 9 ? Ruby is complaining that there is a undefined method called "map", and after doing some research I saw a little piece of code that used the "times" method with it. Surprisingly, I got the code to work. However, I'm confused on why I need to use times.

My original line 9 statement was

```
nameArray = num.map do |x|
```

That doesn't work, but why is the times method needed. How come I just can't use num to show how many times I want to map iterate over x ? Is using times the only way to access the map method ? I'm confused...

Below is the working code, with just line 9 changed.

```
def Array_Maker 
  puts "How many people would you like to enter? : "
    num = gets.chomp.to_i

    nameArray = Array.new(num)

  puts "\nEnter the names of the people you wish to add: "

    nameArray = num.times.map do |x|
    gets.chomp.to_s
  end

  nameArray.each do |x| 
    puts x
  end
end  


Array_Maker()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` method is for Enumerable class however you are using it over a Fixnum. Hence the error.

Fixnum does not have an instance method `map`. Here: (*Thanks to Cary :)*)

```
Fixnum.instance_methods.include?(:map)
# => false
```

Refer to Enumerable#map here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map

When you do `num.times` you are converting `num`(Fixnum) into an [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html) class. Here:

```
num = 1
num.times
# => #<Enumerator: 1:times>
num.times.class
# => Enumerator
```

Since Enumerator class is meant to allow iterations, `map` is a valid method for this class. Therefore you get no error for `num.times.map`.

**Update**

Earlier I had mentioned `map` method is for Array class. Which though true but as Cary pointed out is just *an easy implementation* of Enumerable class. Therefore I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland for correcting my answer and teaching me. :)